# Minitest on Rails 4 & Ruby 2 - getting 'assert_not' to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm trying to use minitest (with rails 4.1.1 & ruby 2.0). For a the below spec, I'm getting an error:

```
  it "is invalid when phone number too short" do
    @contact.phone = "123456789"
    assert_not @contact.valid?
  end


1) Error:
Contact#test_0009_is invalid when phone number too short:
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_not' for #<#<Class:0x007f8d6ac14608>:0x007f8d6b843488>
    test/models/contact_test.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My dev & test for gem file has the following:

```
  gem 'minitest-rails', '~> 2.0.1'
  gem 'minitest', '~> 5.3.4'
```

By the way, I just upgraded to ruby 2.1.2 to no avail.

If available, please share with me clear documentation on setting rails 4 with minitest.

Comment: Basing my question on Rails Testing Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), section 3.4 under **Available Assertions**, it is: `assert_not( test, [msg] )` - Ensures that test is false.

Comment: You can also use `refute`.

Answer (score 0):

The `assert_not` method is added in ActiveSupport::TestCase, and is not present in vanilla Minitest tests. Most likely your test is not using ActiveSupport::TestCase. The easiest way to check is to add the following line to your test:

```
assert_includes self.class.ancestors, ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

The next question is why. I don't know what the rest of your test looks like so I can't say for sure. Whatever you are passing to the `describe` method isn't being matched to ActiveSupport::TestCase. New in minitest-rails 2.0 is the ability to match on an optional second parameter to `describe`. So an easy way to ensure ActiveSupport::TestCase is to provide `:model`.

```
describe "I'm not sure what you are doing here", :model do
  it "is invalid when phone number too short" do
    @contact.phone = "123456789"
    assert_not @contact.valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: @user1322092 It depends on what `Post` is, and what spec_types have been registered for that type. If `minitest-rails` is used and `Post` is an ActiveRecord object, then it will work. Look at [register_spec_type](register_spec_type) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Just found out that `assert_not` is only available inside `ActiveSupport::TestCase` when you use Spec it's not present